# Get rid of border on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/xikopuna/1/edit) of my page. And there is the black bordering around it. I want to have the images span all the way out like [this](http://brunoluciano.me/). I've tried messing with the margins and padding but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: you set your background black in body

Comment: You may want to check your `wrap` styling and the `margin` value...

Comment: I know that.... If I dont do anything it'll be white. @M.chaudhry

Comment: I showed the demo for a reason. To show the border. Or else you would of had to copy it and paste to see what I really mean. @loop_duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of `.wrap{...}`, all it does is add a margin.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Margin of 10px on wrap, changed it to 0:

```
.wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0
}
```